# Unity Rigidbody is sliding after jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like my character to jump diagonally but when it hits the ground it slides.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && isGrounded())
    {
        //jump 
        timeHeld = 0;
        Debug.Log("MouseButtonUp = true");
        rb.AddForce(jumpDirection, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    else if (isGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

this code somehow works but it glitches when the player hits the ground. I need to put some amount of force to get him out of isGrounded() or he will just get some pixels up and be instantly pushed down again.
This is my isGrounded() function

```
private bool isGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2d.bounds.center, boxCollider2d.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, platformLayerMask);
    return raycastHit.collider != null;
}
```

the problem is obviously my distance which is 0.1f in Boxcast(). Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to check the ground by yourself.

1. Add a unity event called OnCollisionEnter
2. Inside, check if the collider is the ground
3. If true, then velocity = zero